# angularjs: Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $filter

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I have defined a very simple filter in my angularjs app (written in Coffeescript), which looks like this:

```
userName = (user) ->
  (user?.match /^user:([^@]+)/)?[1] 

angular.module('myApp.filters', [])
  .filter('userName', -> userName)
```

I want to use this filter in my myApp.services module like this:

```
class MyClassProvider
  this.$inject = ['$filter']
  constructor: ($filter) ->
    @user_filter = $filter 'userName'
    ... more code

angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngSanitize','ngResource','myApp.filters'])
  .provider('MyClassProvider', MyClassProvider)
```

But it gives back the following error (developer console):

```
Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $filter from myApp.services
```

Can somebody help what is the problem?

Comment: geujv, if you'll make a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/) that reproduces the issue, I'll be happy to take a look! You can create an AngularJS + Coffee Plunker by launching the editor, clicking the drop-down on the 'New' button, hovering over 'AngularJS' and clicking the Coffee icon next to the version you want.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have 'ng' in your global dependencies in myApp.services, you can't inject $filter without having angular.

```
angular.module('myApp.services', ['ng', 'ngSanitize','ngResource','myApp.filters'])
  .provider('MyClassProvider', MyClassProvider)
```